# Calculating holidays number from my time off

Tags: formula-field

How can I get number of holidays from my time off in a formula field, I've already defined all my holidays in order to retreive it from my time off days

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the holidays table from formula fields. You would need to use APEX code for this task.

Find an example here: http://forcemonkey.blogspot.nl/2009/11/calculating-business-hours.html

Comment: If you think an answer answers your question, please accept it so others can easily retrieve it as well.